# Detecting scroll of <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I made a `<div>` with an incomplete script;

```js
window.onscroll = function (ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    alert("Bottom!");
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="divName" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:75%;">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</div>
```

How can I activate the alert when the scrollable  reaches the bottom?

Comment: log `window.innerHeight + window.scrollY` and `document.body.offsetHeight` and check to see if your `if` statement will ever trigger.

Comment: This script will trigger when the document has been scrolled all the way to the bottom. Are you trying to have it activate only when the `div` in question is scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: @Rylee yes, only for the `<div>`.